# Is there anyway I can use array to store all video frames (no matter how long the video is) in opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

My computer totally crashes if I am trying to store all video frames in a vector. I know it is memory problem according to some other posts. Is there any other way I can store all video frames in just one container. I am trying this:

```
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(Mat), storage);
```

but I could not get seq elements from seq. Did anyone tried this before?

---

Update:

The crash is due to memory full. It is important to allocate appropriate memory before I allocate video frames into the array and replace the old matrix with new one when the buffer is full.

Comment: Storing whole uncompressed videos in memory is bound to fail for anything but moderately sized ones - for example, a 5 minutes full HD 30 FPS video uncompressed is 4 * 1920 * 1080 * 5 * 30 * 60 = 69 GB, which I'm quite sure you don't have available in RAM. Find another solution, this isn't going to work.

Comment: as always: **don't use obsolete C api**!

Comment: is there any efficient way to access the same video in 5 different thread? I think open 5 video in 5 thread is very inefficient because it's a same video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store these, you need to have enough memory available in ram, which is not possible. You will need to have think of something else. What you’re saying isn’t possible.

Comment: Is there any efficient way to access same video in 5 different thread?